# Kylin installation on CentOS Error /var/lib/docker/overlay2/

Tags: docker, docker-compose, kylin

I am having some trouble installing Apache Kylin on centOS server. I already had install Kylin on this server. But I had to erase all the images from docker with `sudo docker system prune -a`, and then when I run the command below to pull the Kylin image from  Docker Hub it uses the cached files I think.

Command: docker pull apachekylin/apache-kylin-standalone:3.0.1

```
3.0.1: Pulling from apachekylin/apache-kylin-standalone
cbac6436a996: Already exists 
ef7cd122ff67: Already exists 
4218deff225a: Already exists 
e16a6df3203f: Already exists 
0fa067284b01: Already exists 
8a205d5ca91b: Already exists 
d7ce67937c31: Already exists 
f2a74e1fcf1a: Already exists 
43ab431abd59: Already exists 
4da2bcf28ce2: Already exists 
de24ae1dc934: Already exists 
0f0ff3699671: Already exists 
155f1ec45c79: Already exists 
fb7f8f2c76f7: Already exists 
eef58c7f98e9: Already exists 
d3d888485fe6: Already exists 
d43b7a000177: Already exists 
4a00b6a3dc44: Already exists 
638c7082ba84: Already exists 
cedf84f50916: Already exists 
640e40760c9f: Already exists 
60620bc83e11: Already exists 
Digest: sha256:91e55e184ece32324a08020443e8c062b4429061905de1800273b2984b842456
Status: Downloaded newer image for apachekylin/apache-kylin-standalone:3.0.1
docker.io/apachekylin/apache-kylin-standalone:3.0.1
```

Everything looks good, but when I run:

```
docker run -d \
-m 8G \
-p 7070:7070 \
-p 8088:8088 \
-p 50070:50070 \
-p 8032:8032 \
-p 8042:8042 \
-p 16010:16010 \
apachekylin/apache-kylin-standalone:3.0.1
```

It returns:

```
docker: Error response from daemon: open /var/lib/docker/overlay2/af1fbffcc6b8ece6fd63f6d546d29e4363db2618e205b02046df7d32c4928e30/committed: no such file or directory.
See 'docker run --help'.
```

**What can I do? Can I erase the cached image? Or forced to download a new one?**

Answer (score -1):

Simply restart the daemon with `sudo systemctl restart docker` and try again. If error occurs again restart your machine.

Comment: I tried sudo systemctl restart docker and the same error occur.

Comment: How about restarting the machine